# How to get the radio value before radio-group change?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to alert something when i change the radio value 2->0;

alert another thing when i change the radio value 1->2;

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of Category_D_name">
    <ion-card text-wrap>
      <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="items.option" >
        <ion-list-header>
          {{ categoryOption }}.{{ item.name.SortOrder }}
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>不适用</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="0"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>合格</ion-label>
          <ion-radio checked="true" value="1"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>
            不合格
          </ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="2"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-card>
  </ng-container>
```

> ionChange() evnet  Just give me the changed value，But I want to get the value before the change at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to handle this with help of a **`Temp variable`** and `ionChange`

```
 <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="items.option" (ionChange)="selectedRadio($event)">
```

**Component.ts**

```
  tempOption: any;

  selectedRadio(event) {
     if(this.tempOption) {
        if(this.tempOption == 2 &&  event == 0) {
            // do somethig
        }  else if(this.tempOption == 1 &&  event == 2) {
            // do somethig
        }
     }
     this.tempOption = event;
    }
```

hope this helps... :)